# How can I insert a row into a dataframe, while preserving numerical order of row indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe from a machine that samples every 2 miliseconds, so all my row indexes have been reindexed to the machine's timestamps.  There are certain TTL events that can take place at any interval with milisecond precision, so it's possible that a TTL can occur at an odd number of miliseconds.

To simulate this, I have created the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': xrange(10), 'y': xrange(10)})
df = df.ix[2::2]  # now we only have "time sample" every 2 ms
df['events'] = ''  # add a TTL channel
```

The DataFrame now looks like this:

```
x    y       events
2    2    2        NaN
4    4    4        NaN
6    6    6        NaN
8    8    8        NaN

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Now I want to insert an odd-indexed ttl, so I use `DataFrame.loc`:

```
df.loc[3, 'events'] = 'kowabunga!'
```

I obtain the following:

```
     x    y       events
2    2    2        NaN
4    4    4        NaN
6    6    6        NaN
8    8    8        NaN
3  NaN  NaN  kowabunga!

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

The problem is that the numerical order of my indexes (which double as timestamps) is not preserved. How can I actually *insert* the "kowabunga" row such that it resides between index 2 and 4 ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `df.sort(inplace=True)` after all your additions to the data-frame.

Demo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': xrange(10), 'y': xrange(10)})
df = df.ix[2::2]  # now we only have "time sample" every 2 ms
df['events'] = ''  # add a TTL channel
df.loc[3, 'events'] = 'kowabunga!'
df.loc[5, 'events'] = 'kowabunga2!'
df.loc[1, 'events'] = 'kowabunga3!'
df.sort(inplace=True)
print df
```

Output:

```
    x   y       events
1 NaN NaN  kowabunga3!
2   2   2             
3 NaN NaN   kowabunga!
4   4   4             
5 NaN NaN  kowabunga2!
6   6   6             
8   8   8             

[7 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Concise answer with a minimal, working code example -- I'd upvote twice if I could!  Thank you!