# Is treating the integer index of a DataFrame and a resulting SciPy matrix as the same thing a bad idea?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a pipeline that takes in a pandas DataFrame, `df`, with several text columns, concatenates them into a document, and vectorizes the document, resulting in a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`, let's call it `X`.

Later on I do nearest neighbor queries using rows of X (which correspond to rows of my original DataFrame), and when I want to, say, display the text name of one vectors' nearest neighbors, I use the vector's integer position in X like this:

```
>>> print "Nearest neighbor's name is", df.iloc[position_in_x,:]['my_name']
```

Is that a bad move, or can the integer position in the DataFrame be treated as static as long as I'm not adding or removing from the DataFrame?

I wonder how others have handled this. One solution that occurs to me is to make row vectors of `X` a new column in `df`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure about iloc in this case, but if you want more strictness - you can always use [selection by label](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label) with loc attribute. You can use it even after you will change ordering of rows, or after adding new rows. Loc selects rows by index (not integer-location like iloc) which in default case is just index of row in numpy matrix.

```
In [132]: df1
Out[132]: 
   x   y events
0  5  20       
2  7  22       
4  9  24       

In [133]: df2
Out[133]: 
   x   y events
1  6  21       
3  8  23       

In [134]: df3 = df1.append(df2)

In [135]: df3
Out[135]: 
   x   y events
0  5  20       
2  7  22       
4  9  24       
1  6  21       
3  8  23       

In [137]: df3.loc[3,:]
Out[137]: 
x          8
y         23
events      
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

[Also related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533042/how-can-i-insert-a-row-into-a-dataframe-while-preserving-numerical-order-of-row)